# How to change the arc of vertices?

Tags: vertices

You can see how the vertices are right now, but the red line is what I am trying to achieve. How do do I do this?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scale the vertices by -1.0 on, in this case, the Z axis. This should flip them as you wish.